# How to scan plain text QR code using Zxing Android Embedded

Tags: android, zxing

I already got a QR/Barcode Scanner which is working. But I have one problem. The scanner is only reading QR-Codes which contains an url but I want to scan QR-Codes with only text. Does somebody know what the problem could be?

the used library:

```
implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
```

method:

```
private void scanCode() {
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    integrator.setCaptureActivity(CaptureAct.class);
    integrator.setOrientationLocked(false);
    integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
    integrator.setPrompt("Scanning Code");
    integrator.initiateScan();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Would help to mention the library you are using or show some relevant code

Comment: @DavidKroukamp Edit it.

Comment: i think its only not working on the emulator.

Comment: Well that's a minor if negligible issue then at least

Comment: @DavidKroukamp yes right, relieved that i dont have to implement a new scanner

Answer (score 0):

hello you need to use follow configuration

compileSdkVersion 28 // Android 9 (API level 28)
minSdkVersion 24 // Android 7.0 (API level 24)

use dependency of google vision in build.gradle of app

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2'

this is the code for scan the qr code

```
cameraViewQR = findViewById(R.id.cameraView);
    cameraViewQR.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
    qrHolderScreen = cameraViewQR.getHolder();
    barcodeQR = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
            .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)
            .build();
    if (!barcodeQR.isOperational()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Problem Occurred in Setup", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        this.finish();
    }
    cameraSourcePhone = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeQR)
            .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
            .setRequestedFps(24)
            .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(480, 480)
            .build();
    cameraViewQR.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            try {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ScanActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    cameraSourcePhone.start(cameraViewQR.getHolder());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        }
    });
    barcodeQR.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
        @Override
        public void release() {

        }

        @Override
        public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
            final SparseArray<Barcode> barcode = detections.getDetectedItems();
            if (barcode.size() > 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("QRCODE", barcode.valueAt(0));
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
```